# Bold face math symbols using Beamer

Tags: beamer, boldmath

I am trying to do a beamer slide showing a matrix with four boldface math symbols. It works well in article environment but not in beamer. In beamer the cero sub matrix is not bold. I hope that there is a solution to this. Many thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Boldface math}

\[
    \boldsymbol{A}^{\prime}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \boldsymbol{I}_m & \boldsymbol{J}^1_{m,n-a} \\
        \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{I}_{n-1} 
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
    \boldsymbol{A}^{\prime}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbf{I}_m & \mathbf{J}^1_{m,n-a} \\
        \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}_{n-1} 
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get a bold **0** ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp2q5.png)). If you don't, can you provide your `.log` contents?

Comment: Could it be because I am using overleaf?

Comment: Compile with TeX Live 2019 rather than 2020.